# Git : fetch -> unable to create directory

Tags: git

When I do :

git fetch origin refactoring/ABV/some_branch

I get the following error :

```
 * branch            refactoring/ABV/some_branch -> FETCH_HEAD
error: Cannot update the ref 'refs/remotes/origin/refactoring/ABV/some_branch': unable to create directory for .git/logs/refs/remotes/origin/refactoring/ABV/some_branch: No error
! [new branch]      refactoring/ABV/some_branch -> origin/refactoring/ABV/some_branch  (unable to update local ref)
```

Note that after this command, the directory ABV is created, but is empty.
Some of my co-workers have the same problem with this remote branch we want to fetch.

Comment: Is it due to anything with permission, have you checked?

Comment: Did you fix it?